# how to resolve TypeScript error if the function params could be two different types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple function to get the address as a string

```
interface AddressType1 {
  city: string | null; 
  state: string | null;
  postalCode: string null;
}

interface AddressType2 {
  city: string | null; 
  region: string | null;
  postalCode: string | null;
}

export const getAddressString = (
  address: AddressType1 | AddressType2 | null,
): string => {
  if (address != null) {
    return `${address.city ?? ""}, ${address.region ?? address.state ?? ""} ${address.postalCode ?? ""}`;
  }
  return "";
};
```

but typescript return error `Property 'region' does not exist on type 'RoadsideLocation'` and `Property 'state' does not exist on type 'LocationGeocodedAddress'`.

Comment: Try doing `(typeof address === 'AddressType1' ? address.region : address?.state) ?? ''`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `&` intersection :

```
  address: ( AddressType1 & AddressType2 )| null,
```

Answer (score 0):

COnsider next example:

```js
interface AddressType1 {
    city: string | null;
    state: string | null;
    postalCode: string | null;
}

interface AddressType2 {
    city: string | null;
    region: string | null;
    postalCode: string | null;
}

type Union = AddressType1 | AddressType2

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const isType1 = (address: Union): address is AddressType1 => hasProperty(address, 'region');

type Nullable<T> = null | T

const isNull = (str: Nullable<string>): str is null => str === null

const computeAddress = (city: Nullable<string>, postalCode: Nullable<string>) => (stateRegion: Nullable<string>) =>
    [city, stateRegion, postalCode].reduce<string>((acc, elem) => isNull(elem) ? acc : `${acc},${elem}`, '');

export const getAddressString = (
    address: Union,
) => {
    const { city, postalCode } = address;
    const partial = computeAddress(city, postalCode)

    if (isType1(address)) {
        return partial(address.state)


    }
    return partial(address.region)

}
```

Just don't call the function is arguement is `null`.

`computeAddress` is partial application.

If you have a deal with union, try to use [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)